# Django ecommerce website huge product page initial load time (wait)

Tags: python, django, django-models, e-commerce, django-views

I'm just a starter in everything Django related so I apologize upfront for my confusing explanations. I've been trying to resolve some page load issues on a Django based website with an attached ecommerce module.

The initial page load time is huge, around 5 sec, point after which everything goes/loads smoothly.

- Here is a screengrab from firebug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiPMQ.jpg
- The link to the dev enviroment: http://bit.ly/13G7jNp (product page)

This enormous load time is occurring on all pages that are related to products (in my case the  single product page and the cart). Weirdly enough the listings are fine (category pages).

My next guess is that the load time is caused by some product related queries, so I've searched further the code and I've came accross the main.py file which contains a "product_view" definition.

The code goes like this:

```
def product_view(request,shortcode,product_id,variation_id,stub):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product.unmoderated.select_related(),pk=product_id)
    variation = get_object_or_404(ProductVariation.objects.select_related(),pk=variation_id)
    print variation.__dict__
    if not product.active:
        c = {}
        return render_to_response('main/product_inactive.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


    links = ['main_product_view','main_product_variation'+str(variation.id)]

    c = {'links':links, 'product':product, 'variation':variation, 'categories':get_categories(), 'brands':get_brands(), 'title':product.name}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('main/product.html', c,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def product_view_json(request,shortcode,product_id,variation_id,stub):
    try:
        product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
        variation = get_object_or_404(ProductVariation,pk=variation_id)

        thumbnail = get_thumbnail(variation.image, '220x220', crop='center', quality=80)

        d = {"title":product.name, "brand":product.merchant.name, "price":str(product.base_price+variation.price), "image":thumbnail.url}

        out = json.dumps(d)

        r = HttpResponse(out)
        r['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';

        return r
    except:
        return HttpResponse("Error")
```

At this point I'm lost, not sure if I'm on the right path to resolve this issues or what else should I do.

Also, there are a few missing images, still haven't banged those out but it's not entirely relevant at this point. Furthermore, memcache is enabled, the static template files are not affecting at all the page load time (stripped down the templates to text only) and mod_pagespeed module is enabled for the Apache environment.

I would really appreciate any input on this. Thank you!

Comment: Try [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) it will show you how many queries have executed and how much time each query has taken. Then you can improve from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines in `product_view` are not correct

```
product = get_object_or_404(Product.unmoderated.select_related(),pk=product_id)
variation = get_object_or_404(ProductVariation.objects.select_related(),pk=variation_id)
```

Change it to

```
product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
variation = get_object_or_404(ProductVariation,pk=variation_id)
```

The `.select_related()` will try to prefetch and load all objects and their related objects, which will be resource consuming.

Comment: Thanks Rohan for your reply but unfortunately this didn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems more of a HTML issue rather than django issue. Look into few things

- If you are using Pop-ups then load time is increased because they are
  loaded as the page loads.
- Then see whether you are calling the .js and .css files remotely or are they
  placed on your server. so if they are local it boosts up the
  response.

Just have a look at these and let me know if there is any of those that exists

Comment: Will double check these and I'll let you know. I'm rolling back now some backups just to have a clean start, once again.

Comment: Also check for DB. Is it placed locally on the server or called remotely.

Comment: @AdrianApan has the problem been solved, if affirmative then share your solution and if someone's answer has helped then mark it as up vote or correct answer. That would be appreciated.